# sql - How to find max over a category

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

How do I get the output like this in sql. I tried group by but it is not giving months, is there an easier way to do this.

```
select * from t1 order by 1,2 ;
 id | month | amnt
----+-------+------
  1 | feb   |   50
  1 | jan   |   20
  2 | apr   |   30
  2 | feb   |   50
  2 | jan   |   30
  2 | mar   |   70
(6 rows)

Output
=========

 id | month | amnt
----+-------+------
  1 | feb   |   50
  2 | mar   |   70
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Show sql that you have tried

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  (`SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? Something else...?)

Comment: Depends on dbms. If its SQL Server then you could do a common table expression with a row_number function, having partitioned it by the id and ordered by the amnt desc. Then select form the cte where rn=1

Comment: What it the requested result in case of a tie between 2 records of the same id?

Comment: `select a.*
    from t1 a, (select id, max(amnt) mamt from t1 group by 1) b
    where a.id = b.id
    and a.amnt = b.mamt ;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have window functions

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By id order by amnt desc)
```

Returns

```
id  month   amnt
2   mar     70
1   feb     50
```

Comment: This syntax is hideous and beautiful at the same time :-) +1

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thanks for the grin  :)

Comment: I tried the below sql, `select a.*
    from t1 a, (select id, max(amnt) mamt from t1 group by 1) b
    where a.id = b.id
    and a.amnt = b.mamt ;` but the issue with how to write a generic sql for the "ties", I guess I need to look for some window functions in whatever the sql product I am going to write this for.